# Visual Studio 2019 incorrect project properties appearance

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I want to add path to python library through project properties, but my properties look like that (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjmVu.png)
instead of
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtA0I.png)

I don't know what's wrong and can't find anything about it.

Comment: What you have open is the properties for a project, but the other example image you're showing is what happens when you open up the configuration manager for the solution. A project and a solution are not the same thing.

Comment: I took the example image from that video (https://youtu.be/oZQ_c89HFU0?list=PLIWDHtAzf8ccODCrS1F1jQ4az840QDpB1&t=180) and they were clicking on the project properties. But instead of "All configurations" i have "N/A". And in solution propirties there is nothing like that either.

Comment: When i created c++ empty project it finally worked. But it still not working with the python application. Any reason for that? And how can i create python project if i dont see this as an option while creating new project?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.